# Import Notes in an object

Tags: data-loader, import, data-import

I would like to import Notes via INSERT in a particular object using **Dataloader.io** , have tried various times but not able to. Can anyone tell me the .csv file format which needs to be used while inserting notes.

How I need to map the fields in **dataloader.io.**

I get the error

> "Error: ID value of incorrect record type "

[image]

Comment: What data does your .csv contain and what are you mapping to? Could you give a small sample? The Note object has the following fields: Body, IsDeleted, IsPrivate, OwnerId, ParentId and Title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Used Data Loader to Retrieve the data from the Org and then made the changes in the CSV file. Then I tried to Change the ParentID to Contact and inserting the Note CSV in my org through Data Loader. It works fine. 
I have also checked the OwnerID, It is optional if you are putting any OwnerID It will take the Owner ID as the user through which you are logged in Data Loader.

[image: Workbench Result and the Second record is aligned with the Contact Object]

Comment: Can contentNote be inserted in a particular objects through dataloader.io, i got the error

Error converting value to correct data type: Path

Answer (score 0):

I just use a file to import notes and it works for me. Here is the file format.

```
Body,Owner ID,Parent ID,Private,Title
Test Body,00528000000MfNqAAK,0012800000EuFZSAA3,FALSE,Test
```

Check your file i think you are missing some fields.

Comment: Lets say I want to add notes in contact object then, ParentID will be contact ID but then what will be OwnerID??

Comment: ownerid is current user id if you don't specify it. SF will auto populate it.